# How to prove X = A $\cup$ B given subset conditions?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

## Problem

Given sets $\mathcal A$, $\mathcal B$, $\mathcal Y$, let $\mathcal X$ be a set with the following properties:

- $\mathcal X$ $\supset$ $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal X$ $\supset$ $\mathcal B$,
- if $\mathcal Y$ $\supset$ $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal Y$ $\supset$ $\mathcal B$  , then $\mathcal Y$ $\supset$ $\mathcal X$

Prove that $\mathcal X$ = $\mathcal A$ $\cup$ $\mathcal B$.

---

## My work

Let $\mathcal x$ be an element of set $\mathcal X$ and $\mathcal y$ be an element of set $\mathcal Y$.

If $\mathcal X \supset\mathcal A$, then $\mathcal x$ $\in$ $\mathcal A$, then $\mathcal x$ $\in$ $\mathcal X$. 
 If $\mathcal X \supset\mathcal B$, then $\mathcal y$ $\in$ $\mathcal B$, then $\mathcal y$ $\in$ $\mathcal Y$.

If $\forall$ $\ x$ $\in$ $\mathcal A$, $\ x$ $\in$ $\mathcal X$; and $\forall$ $\ y$ $\in$ $\mathcal B$, $\ y$ $\in$ $\mathcal Y$, then $\mathcal X = \mathcal A \cup \mathcal B$.

---

This is an introductory problem in a Real Analysis course I'm doing on my own. I'm an Engineer trying to acquire a deeper mathematical maturity. The book I'm following doesn't bring answers, ergo, the question. But more than a "Right or Wrong" answer, I'd like an evaluation concerning the rigor - or the lack thereof - of the answer I provided.

Comment: Just a light hearted comment: who uses caligraphic symbols for sets? Isn't it  a pain to type these?

Comment: hahah. It is indeed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that $A,B, X$ are specific sets that exist and a given to you.  They do not change.

$Y$ can be any set in the world.

So let $Y = A\cup B$.

(We know in general that $A \subset A\cup B$ and $B\subset A\cup B$.  This isn't just true of *these* sets.  This would be true for *any* sets, $K$ and $M$.  It is *always* true that $K \subset K\cup M$. That is because  $K\cup M$ is the set of all elements that are in $K$ or in $M$.  If $x \in K$ then it is one of the elements that are in $K$ or in $M$.  So all the elements of $K$ are elements in $K\cup M$.  So $K\subset K\cup M$.)

$A\subset A\cup B$ or in other words $Y= A\cup B \supset A$.  And $B\subset A\cup B$ or in other words $Y= A\cup B \supset B$.

But we have a condition that if  $Y\sup A$ and $Y\sup B$ then we will have $Y\sup X$.

And we have do have that $A\cup B \supset A$ and $A\cup B \supset B$ so we must have $A\cup B\supset X$.

On the other hand:  $A\cup B \subset X$.  We know this because if $x \in A\cup B$ then either $x \in A$ or $x\in B$.  If $x \in A$ then, because $X\sup A$ so every element in $A$ is in $X$, we know $x \in X$.  And if $x \in B$ then $x\in X$ because $X\sup B$ and that's what $X\sup B$ means.  So either way $x \in X$.

So every element in $A\cup B$ is in $X$ so $A\cup B \subset X$.

We also have $A\cup X \supset X$ so every element in $X$ is in $A\cup B$.

So $A\cup B$ and $X$ both have the exact same elements.

So $A\cup B = X$.

....

As to your work:

"x be an element of set X... If X⊃A, then x ∈ A,then x ∈ X"

"If $X \subset A$"  No if about it!  You were *told* that $X \supset A$ so nothing to speculate.

"then $x \in A$".  That's not true.  Just pick an $x$ that is in $X$ but not in $A$.  Then $x$ will not be in $A$.

"then x ∈ X"  But... you *already* said that.

... and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is not correct. There is no $\mathcal Y$ to begin with so your first statement doesn't make sense.

First verify that $\mathcal A \cup \mathcal B \subset \mathcal X$. This is easy from the first condition and the definition of union.

Next let us prove that $\mathcal X \subset \mathcal A \cup \mathcal B$.  Let us prove this by contradiction. Suppose $x \in \mathcal X \setminus \mathcal A \cup \mathcal B$. Take $\mathcal Y=\mathcal A \cup \mathcal B \setminus \{x\}$. Use the second condition given to show that we must have $\mathcal X \subset\mathcal A \cup \mathcal B \setminus \{x\}$. Arrive at a contardiction by observing that $x$ belongs to LHS but not to RHS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I noticed, thanks to your comment, that I had forgotten the Y in the first line of my problem statement. Then, I edited the question.

Comment: How do you read the slash in $\mathcal X$ \ $\mathcal A \cup \mathcal B$?

Comment: I used slash to to denote set difference: $A \setminus B$ is the set of  all points which belong to $A$ but not to $B$.

Comment: " I noticed, thanks to your comment, that I had forgotten the Y in the first line of my problem statement. Then, I edited the question." What you edited no longer makes any sense.  It only made sense *without* specifying the $Y$.  Consider $X = \{a,b,c,d,e\}$ and $A=\{a\}$ and $B=\{b\}$ and $Y = \{a,b,c,d,e,f,g$.  Then $X\supset A$ $X\supset B$, $Y\supset A$, $Y\supset B$ and $Y\supset X$.  So all conditions are true.  But $A \cup B = \{a,b\} \ne \{a,b,c,d,e\} = X$.